# RStudio Server CentOS wrong ELF class

Tags: r, centos, rstudio, centos6, rstudio-server

I am using CentOS 6 and trying to get RStudio Server running.  When I do a rstudio-server verify-installation the following is displayed:

> Stopping rstudio-server:                                   [  OK  ]
>       /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rsession: error while loading shared libraries: libgfortran.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
>       Starting rstudio-server:                                   [  OK  ]

Verified the the 64 bit version of java, R and RStudio.

Anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Did you install the 64 bit version of libgfortran?

Answer (score 0):

You version of libgfortran is not 64 bit, to get RStudio working you need to install the 64 version of libgfortran. See [this link](http://jermdemo.blogspot.com/2011/08/installing-rstudio-server-on-scientific.html) and [this link](http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/problems/1805-rstudio-server-centos-6) for more info.